# xml sitemap module : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: xml-sitemap

I installed the [xml sitemap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap), when I go to my sitemap.xml page, it give me an error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error.

How can I find spaces that shouldn't be there? How to find spaces before `<?php` tag, but omit files where they are legitimate, like theme files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting a white space before the php tag in the settings.php file.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this actually fixed my issue!