# Blank spaces opening RSS XML file - How to solve?

Tags: 7, meta-tags, xml-sitemap, rdf

All of the sudden, we are experiencing problems with our RSS feed which comes with the Drupal core 7.x . It is no longer valid due to two spaces before the opening XML tag. The following error is what I get in the feed validator:

> line 1, column 2: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:2: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

So I am aware of other related posts on Stack Exchange and tried the things mentioned in:

- [Approach to removing extra space at beginning of RSS file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60509/approach-to-removing-extra-space-at-beginning-of-rss-file)
- [xml sitemap module : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document [closed]](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140840/xml-sitemap-module-xml-declaration-allowed-only-at-the-start-of-the-document)
- [RSS Feed does not validate using Views RSS module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86169/rss-feed-does-not-validate-using-views-rss-module)

These are the things we did do so far:

- Checked all PHP-files on the website for containing blank spaces before the opening tags. There were a few, we fixed them all but no help.
- Changed the default theme to another theme, making sure it is not theme related.
- When I create a custom RSS feed with Views, the same two blank spaces show up before the XML opening tag.
- I checked every page, block and view that has manually written PHP tags everywhere and deleted every space that could cause this.
- All modules and Drupal core is updated to the most recent versions.
- I checked on the Drupal forum for related issues in XML Sitemap, Metatag, RDF, Schema.org (modules we are using) with no success. I disabled every one of the above mentioned modules one by one, but with no success.
- Eventually we exported the complete website, except the sites/default/files/ folder which contains no PHP files anyway, and imported it local. The blank spaces are gone in the local setup.

What makes it a bit difficult too, is that I have no idea when the RSS feed went broken. It can be between a week and a few months, making it difficult to filter out when I updated some contrib modules.

So we are quite desperate in finding this, especially since the problem doesn't exist in a local setup. We have a news website so having a working RSS feed is pretty important.

We must be overlooking something, but have no idea what it can be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue was a module which had two blank spaces AFTER the closing PHP-tags in its .module file. All the topics I've found on the internet only mentioned blank space before the opening PHP-tags, so if anyone else ever have this issue, also look in the closing tags

Comment: `.module` files are not suppose to have closing tags.

Answer (score 3):

Some more troubleshooting ideas:

- Do the spaces only appear on the RSS page, or also on other pages? That could tell you whether the problem is in a central place or a template/include-file that is only loaded for the RSS feed.
- You can use `var_dump(get_included_files())` (ideally in the template, just before the XML is generated) to see a list of all PHP files that have been included so far. This might help with investigating - look for closing PHP tags at the end of the files, print statements, etc.

Also, an idea for a dirty workaround (may cause other problems, but could be worth a try if it's urgent): `ob_start()` buffers all output, while `ob_end_clean()` deletes it. So if you put an `ob_start()` in the top of your index.php and an `ob_end_clean()` at the start of the RSS template, this *might* let you discard the spaces. (It shouldn't affect anything else, because the buffer is flushed automatically if it's still open when the script ends.)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. The issue was a module which had two blank spaces AFTER the closing PHP-tags in its .module file. All the topics I've found on the internet only mentioned blank space before the opening PHP-tags, so if anyone else ever have this issue, also look in the closing tags.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a problem to watch out for. Drupal coding standards actually say to omit the closing PHP tag entirely: It's optional, and removing it reduces avoids the risk of whitespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

To debug whitespaces in the page output, you can use [XDebug PHP extension](https://xdebug.org/). Here are the suggested options in your XDebug PHP's ini file:

```
; Data
xdebug.default_enable = 1           ; bool: The stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event.
xdebug.collect_vars = 1             ; bool: Gather information about which variables are used in a certain scope.
xdebug.show_local_vars=1            ; int: Generate stack dumps in error situations.
xdebug.collect_assignments=1        ; bool: Controls whether Xdebug should add variable assignments to function traces.
xdebug.collect_params=4             ; int1-4: Collect the parameters passed to functions when a function call is recorded.
xdebug.collect_return=1             ; bool: Write the return value of function calls to the trace files.
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256 ; int: Amount of array children and object's properties are shown.
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024    ; int: Max string length that is shown when variables are displayed.
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=5      ; int: How many nested levels of array/object elements are displayed.
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0             ; int: Show the difference in memory usage between function calls.
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0       ; bool: Show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised.
xdebug.max_nesting_level=256        ; int: Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection.
```

Then either use step-by-step debugging mode, or temporary activate [`xdebug.auto_trace=1`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) to generate trace files within your `xdebug.trace_output_dir` on every request.

Then request XML file and check the trace file. It'll take a while to track down the source of it by checking the returns of certain functions near end, but at least it's possible.

---

Alternatively disable as many modules as you can and you can find the problem by trial and error.

---

If you believe one of your `.module`'s file could consist trailing spaces, the following `ex` command (part of Vim) will remove any of these:

```
ex +'bufdo!%s/\s\+$//e' -scxa **/*.*
```

<sub>Note: If your shell supports [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option), use `**` for recursive scan. Enable by: `shopt -s globstar`.</sub>

---

Another way is to run your files through the coding standards using [Coder module](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder). After installation, the following command will find the issue related hidden trailing spaces:

```
phpcs --standard=Drupal some_folder/
```

To fix the issue in-place, try this one:

```
phpcbf --standard=Drupal some_folder/
```

<sup>Note: Before run, make sure you've everything committed or made a backup, as above command will reformat all your files.</sup>